# My mediaplayer doesn't "loop" well

Tags: android

I have a class that extends Service, where i have a MediaPlayer that manages the background music of my app.

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background_music);
player.setLooping(true);
```

The problem is that it doens't "loop" well: I mean, when the mp3 file ends, there's a second of silence before it starts again.
But, in the mp3 file, actually, there's not any second of silence.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I agree with bofredo android doesn't support breakfree music yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. This bug has been there for ages now, but they still didn't fix it and it does not look like they are going to do it in the close future!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18756

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SoundPool to play your audio file (it loops very well and without delay, however might be inappropriate for some audio resources).

Here is some kind of implementation (deprecation removal and appropriate closing of resource is left as a homework :))

```
SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(audioResource);
pool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        if (0 == status) {
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1f, 1f, 10, -1 /* looping parameter */, 1f);
        }
    }
});
pool.load(afd, 10);
afd.close();
```

From other side if MediaPlayer is a must have you might look into method **setNextMediaPlayer**. So the idea is to initialize several MediaPlayers for the same file (what a mess) and set them in a smart way.

Comment: only 5 seconds long audios